# Average velocity showing different results

Tags: kinematics, velocity, differentiation, calculus, speed

I was solving a question, in which, a particle has travelled a distance $s$, with initial velocity $0$ and constant acceleration.
So the equation of motion becomes,

$$ v = a t \tag{1} $$
and

$$ v = \sqrt{2 a s} \tag{2} $$

So, both represent velocities and by definition both their averages must represent the same thing.

$$ \langle v \rangle_{s} = \frac{\int v \,ds}{\int ds} \tag{3} $$

So, $$\langle v(t)\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{as}{2}}$$

But, $$\langle v(s)\rangle = \frac{2}{3}×\sqrt{2as}$$

So, why do these two functions give different values?

Comment: In general, averaging over distance won't give the same value as averaging over time.  A classic example is the average orbit radius, see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49267/16685

Comment: @PM2Ring but why is that? They both are the same things, and a specific instant both must provide the same value, then why the average is different? Is there some underlying mathematics that I'm not considering?

Comment: This question is probably more on-topic on Math.SE, but I guess it's ok here, because this effect often arises in physics.

Comment: As you note in the question, the mean value comes from an integral. But consider the effect of a non-linear change of variable on the scale on the X axis.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13855/123208 Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411834/207316

Comment: Here's another important example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law "the location of the peak of the spectral distribution for Planck's law depends on the choice of spectral variable"

Comment: @PM2Ring is OP actually trying to show that $\langle v\rangle_t=\langle v\rangle_s$? Or that $\langle v(t)\rangle_s$, when done wrong isn't the same as $\langle v(s)\rangle_s$? I read this post as asking the latter, but your comments suggest reading it as the former.

Comment: @KyleKanos I expected that average of velocity as a function of time, and function of displacement should give same value, (so I'm assuming <v>_s means average of velocity where v is a function of displacement), then yeah I mean the former.

Comment: @Agent_A I'm using $\langle v\rangle_k$ to mean the average of $v$ with respect to $k$ (which would be $t$ or $s$). In such a case, it would probably be rather rare to expect that the time-average of one function is equal to the spatial-average of the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to show that the temporal averaged function is equal to the spatially averaged function,
$$\langle v\rangle_t=\langle v\rangle_s,$$
then several of the comments and other answer apply: integrating functions of different arguments ($v(t)$, $v(s)$) over their dependent variables ($t$, $s$) generally yields different results and should not be surprising.

From your comments, however, it appears that you are trying to apply the $t\to s$ mapping on the time-averaged quantity and expecting that it also will be the spatially-averaged quantity:
$$\varphi\left(\langle v(t)\rangle_t\right)_s=\varphi\left(\frac{1}{2}at\right)_s=\sqrt{\frac{sa}{2}}\neq\langle v(s)\rangle_s$$
which is off by a factor of $4/3$.

The reason this doesn't work is essentially the same as the first paragraph of my answer: you are averaging two different function over two different regions. Pictorially, the time-dependent velocity curve is in green and the spatial-dependent velocity in purple (using $a=1/2$ in both so that $v(t)=t/2$ and $v(s)=\sqrt{s}$). Since the shape of the curves are different, with one always larger than the other, the averages will be necessarily different also.
[image]
([via Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/graphing-calculator))
In order to transform the temporal average to make it equal to the spatial average, you either have to transform $v(t)$ into $v(s)$ before taking the average *or* adjust the final result by accounting for the difference between the two curves.

Comment: @Agent_A a bit later than I'd have liked to post an amendment, but I got it done.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have 2 different functions. So when you take the average of different functions - you'll get different averages in general - because they are different functions.

Have you heard of function compositions? Consider 2 functions $f$ and $g$. Now combine them together to get a **new and completely different** function $f \circ g$. Do not think that $f \circ g = f$.

The function $f$ takes some element, say, $x$ to $y$. So I may write $y = f(x)$.
The function $g$ takes some element, say, $k$ to $l$. So I may write $l = g(k)$.

However the function $f\circ g$ or $f(g(k))$ is different. It takes some of the $k$'s to some of the $y$'s. Functions have names, so call it $h$ or house or star or whatever you like, so $h = f \circ g$.

Remember the chain rule? The chain rule states, the derivative of the **composition** is equal to the derivative of the outside times the derivative of the inside. 3 different functions. But notice that the derivative of the composition isn't equal to the derivative of the outside. So the average of a composition we shouldn't expect to be equal to the average of the outside. For clarity sake at the beginning stages, you must have good notation. For the 1) function name, 2) domain elements. But in physics (even in quantum physics) there is an abuse of notation which is very confusing at first. And by that I mean, you use the same symbol to mean multiple things, even in a single line. We get used to it, but notice $x = x(t)$ or $v = v(t)$. It's fine, but notice two different $x$'s and two different $v$'s. In math class, we see $y = f(x)$, you wouldn't see $f = f(x)$. But it's ok.

In your question, you started from equation $(1)$. Time is a function of position, so you inserted $t(s)$ into equation $(1)$ to get a composition function $v(t(s))$. But $v(t)$ and $v(t(s))$ (or in short $v(s)$) are not the same functions. Both deal with velocity, but the new function $v(t(s))$ should be given a different function name like $g$. A function is more that just having the same outputs. Notice that the functions $x$ and $x^3$ both have the exact same range. They output all possible values, but yet, they are different functions. Or consider the function $1 \mapsto 10$, $2 \mapsto 11$, $3\mapsto 12$. And consider the function $0.01 \mapsto 10$, $0.02 \mapsto 11$, $0.03 \mapsto 12$. Different functions. I didn't check your work, but hopefully this answer helps, or gets you thinking about related math topics that is causing confusion.